# Radio signal strength or frequency to determine absolute position of a reciprocating system?

Tags: radio, distance

I have a highly constrained mechanical system consisting of a bar that moves along a straight path for a distance of 40', reciprocating 7 times a minute.
I want to determine the position of the bar within 1%, throughout its cycle. I thought using a low power transmitter and measuring signal strength might be the best way to go, with a transmitter on the moving bar and a fixed receiver at the end of the assembly. I do have power constraints on the transmitter, being battery powered and a constant on source I need +1yr battery life.
Is there a better way to do this?

An additional constraint is that the system is installed in a hazardous location with an explosive atmosphere. That precludes using lasers, cameras etc. We have a suitable radio that is hazloc classified, and the receiving antenna is easy to source, which is why I was thinking signal strength.

Comment: why have you chosen radio over simpler technologies? (eg point a camera at it)  how many kilograms can the battery weigh?

Comment: What moves the bar? What does it move on?

Comment: 40’ as in 12 meters?

Comment: Laser is what you ought to consider before anything else. The only drawback is that the lens needs to be kept clean.

Comment: A camera is not a simpler technology.

Comment: A bridle with a large flywheel moves the system

Comment: Cannot use a laser.

Comment: 40' = 12m yes. thats the longest, but we also have shorter throw systems

Comment: What moves the bar? Is it motorized, or on wheels? Can you just measure some type of rotation instead, using an encoder? I wouldn't discount the camera idea either -- if there's a contrasting background, edge detection even on live video is pretty straightfoward. Much easier (and more accurate) than time-of-flight, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Using radio signal power, while it can work, has a lot of issues related to interference and multi path at least, which make it very imprecise.

A much more accurate solution involves measuring time of flight, probably using a laser-based solution to have a narrow beam.

Just place the ToF sensor at a fixed position at the end of the path, pointers towards the moving part. Make sure there is a reflecting surface facing it on the moving part, and it’s done.

The only difficulty here would be to find a sensor that works at such distances: many sensors stop at a few meters, but some definitely work at those longer distances. [Here’s one](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4058) working at up to 40m according to its specs, but if you search for “long distance ToF sensor” or “long range ToF sensor” you’ll find plenty of other sensors with ranges up to 100m and more.

One other advantage of this solution is that you don’t need any power on the moving part, just a passive reflector. The sensor itself is on the fixed part, where I suppose you won’t have power supply constraints. If you do, it’s just a trade off between how often you measure and how much power you can draw.

Another possibility is to count motor steps or wheel turns. Depending on the exact setup of what moves the bar that could yield a very precise measure. But if your goal is to have a secondary source to check that the bar is where it’s supposed to be that would work.

There are other possibilities such as contact sensors along the path but this is probably overkill.

Comment: I expanded the question with more constraints. TOF isn't going to work as those systems are not classified for hazardous locations.

Comment: How large is the moving part?  What moves it (chain drive, belt drive, elves ...)?  What size / shape / weight restraints are there?  High vibration? Temperature extremes?  Solar load?  IOW any useful information?